# Datagridview cell wrap mode

Tags: vb.net, text, datagridview, cell

I have a datagridview that contains text values. Some of these text values are too long for the cell. I want the the cell to simply not show the letters that don't fit.

Like this:

```
+----------+
|John Johns|
+----------+
```

Setting `Me.dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True` give this:

```
    +----------+
    |John      |
    |Johnson   |
    +----------+
```

while setting `Me.dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.False` gives this result:

```
+----------+
|John Jo...|
+----------+
```

I can't resize the columns as space is limited i simply want to show as much of the cell text as possible.

Comment: What is your question? If the user holds the mouse over a cell with info that does not, it will show in a tooltip type window.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: I do not understand what the question is… it appears that setting the wrap mode to false is giving you what you are asking for. As per the second sentence in your question _” I want the the cell to simply not show the letters that don't fit.”_ this appears to be the third pictured description where wrap mode is false. What are you asking?

Comment: i want it like the first pic. In the third one i lose three letters because of the dots that automatically get put in. i want letters to fill the remaining space not dots.

Comment: I am limited on space so any extra letters i can squeeze in will be useful.

Comment: When the dots appear… it means the string is too long to fit in the column width. In the first example, it appears to show “John Johns” and that is the whole name. If the first example contains “John Johnson” and does NOT have the three dots… then you may want to show this in the grid and the data for those cells. The three dots are built into the `DataGridView` to indicate just this situation and if you want to change this behavior, I am confident you will have to do this yourself.

Comment: Show an example (code/picture) where the `datagridview` cell displays like the top example and the cell does NOT contain three dots AND the WHOLE string is NOT displayed. If the string is too long... three dots will show at the end of the cell.

Comment: Thanks JohnG "John Johns" is how i want it to display but i can only get it to display "John Jo...". Look like i'll have to determine the width and shorten the string before i put it into the cell.